# how to create big shadow for icon toolbar in android

Tags: android, kotlin

big shadow in myket app :

[image: shadow]

how to create big shadow looks like a picture please help me ?

Comment: I think the effect is added by setting the background(or foreground) resource to be selectableItemBackgroundBorderless: `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Comment: i added this into my custom toolbar but ... dont work !!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. "don't work" is not a helpful problem description. If you want someone to help you, please [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve]. What do you expect to happen when you run it? What happens instead? Any errors? You may want to take the [tour] of the site to understand how to ask a good question that will get good answers.

Comment: i added the radius in my style for Custom ToolBar !! and Worked :)